# What is the prefered way to reuse layouts in an android chat app?

Tags: android, android-layout, chat, code-reuse

I want to make an android chat app. I made a simple layout for the chat part. I made two layouts, my message and their message. Each of them only have one text view. Imagine that now I want to add a layout for a picture with a caption. In this case, I have to build two layout. One for my message and second for incoming message or their message. But if I do this for every possible message, the number of layout increases and also there are a lot of repetitive things in my layouts.

[image: Telegram app]
Like in this layout, you can see that in my and their message there is an image and a caption and these two layouts have similarities. I want to make a layout with image and caption and then use it in my or their message. In this case, I can easily update my layouts and save myself creating lots of layouts for each possible message. What is the best way to do this, or it's impossible or not good?

I know that I can reuse layout in two different ways. first by using include keyword in layout and the second one is to inflate layout. For example like this:

```
    ConstraintLayout item = findViewById(R.id.main);
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    item.addView(child);
```

What is the best method to reuse layouts and prevent creating layout which only are different slightly and how existing chat applications do the same? I'm using recycler view for chat layout.

Comment: Use RV with multiple view types. Each view type (your text, their text, your image, their image, bla bla bla) will have a different view type and a separate layout. You inflate them in the RV adapter as any other list item

Answer (score 1):

Use `recycle view` instead and use different views for the different views. Check the message type (myMessage,their message,any other) and change your views using an adpater.

In your adapter,

```
 @Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == 0) {
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row_sender, parent, false);
        return new ChatViewHolder2(v);
    } else if(viewType ==1){
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row_receiver, parent, false);
        return new ChatViewHolder1(v);
    }else {
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_chat_header, parent, false);
        return new ChatHeaderViewHolder(v);
    }
}
```

and use 3 `viewHolders` in your adapter,

```
 public class ChatViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ChatViewHolder1(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
          ...
    }
    }
```

---

```
 public class ChatHeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    public ChatHeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
         ......
    }
}
```

---

```
 public class ChatViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ChatViewHolder2(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      ...
     }
 }
```

Comment: This is not what I meant. I know how to do this. I want to create a layout with picture and caption and then reuse it for my and also their message instead of creating two layouts with picture and caption.

Comment: Do you want different views for the different user types(my,sender) and header. So this is the best way. Other wise you can use one layout. within the layout you can show and hide views according to the user type.

Comment: I'm using this in my project. What i mean is that instead of  building two layouts for my and their message with an image and caption, I build one layout with image and caption then inflate or include it in my and their message.

Comment: can you show me a kind of  image of your chat that you are going to build.

Comment: I updated my question. It's hard for me to explain.

Comment: @MehranJalili the best way is doing this with adapter as I mentioned in my answer. That is the best practice.  It also can be done as you said But it is not the recommended way to do a thing like this. Most of the chat applications use `Adapter`s with `recycleview`s.

Answer (score -3):

Use  attribute in the xml to reuse layout.
like `<Include>`

Comment: this is really vague and doesn't really answer the question. Please consider providing some more information.